# Copy Dynamic Column From One Workbook to Another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set that as an output of an estimating hours program, I am writing in VBA to copy the values in a column and paste them to a workbook, who's name I define in an inputbox.  The problem is the number of rows in the column on the estimating hours output sheet changes and right now my VBA has hard-coded cells in it.  What I want to do is create a dynamic copy of the column where it starts at cell D13 and copy's the column down to the last value, except it moves up 1 cell as the last row contains a total row.

Below is the code I have so far

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Method()

    Dim bookIn As String
    Dim bookOut As String
    Dim X As String

    'Take in data to copy from estimating hours program'
    bookIn = InputBox("Enter workbook name:", "Workbook name")

    'Take in wookbook name to save file to'
    X = InputBox("Set work book name:")


    Workbooks.Add

    'Save new workbook in folder'
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\BradM\Desktop\RET_DATA_ACTUAL\" & X & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False


    With ActiveWorkbook

    'Insert Tooling'

    'Copy column (What I want to be dynamic, start copy at cell D13 to last row with data, then move up 1 row to account for the total row)'
    Workbooks(bookIn).Worksheets("Production Hours").Range("D13:D45").Copy _

    'PasteSpecial to paste values'
    Workbooks(X).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    End With

    End Sub
```

Please let me know if anything else is needed, 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there.  This seems a lot like this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242393/how-to-copy-dynamic-range-in-excel-sheet-using-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sean pointed out in the comments you would need to get the last row to make it a dynamic range. On another note, if it's just values that you are transferring between sheets then it is best to avoid using copy and paste. You could directly set the destination cells equals to the source data as shown below.

```
Sub Copy_Method()

    Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet

    Dim bookIn As String
    Dim bookOut As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim X As String

    'Take in data to copy from estimating hours program'
    bookIn = InputBox("Enter workbook name:", "Workbook name")

    'Take in wookbook name to save file to'
    X = InputBox("Set work book name:")

    'Save new workbook in folder'        [Note we have reduced the add and save as into a single line]
    Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\BradM\Desktop\RET_DATA_ACTUAL\" & X & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Set wsOutput = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    Set wsInput = Application.Workbooks(bookIn).Worksheets("Production Hours")

    'Get last row'      [Note that we subtracted 1 from the lastrow value since you don't want totals]
    lastRow = wsInput.Cells(wsInput.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row - 1

    'destination=source
    wsOutput.Range("A1:A" & lastRow - 12) = wsInput.Range("D13:D" & lastRow).value

End Sub
```

There are far more elegant and dynamic ways to adjust the above code, but this should suffice to demonstrate not using copy/paste (Nb. copy/paste is slower and can increase the risk of errors)

Comment: Thank you very much for your code, however, after testing I keep getting a Run-time error: Application-defined or object-defined error on the destination=source line.

Comment: I've edited the code a bit, see if it gives you an error still?

Comment: No, it did not this time, thank you so much! Worked perfectly!